# What functions satisfy the product relationship $f(x)=\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ f( c^n x)}{f(c^{n+1} x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $f()$ be positive, real and analytic.

Suppose, $f()$ satisfies the following property
\begin{align}
f(x)=\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ f( c^n x)}{f(c^{n+1} x)}
\end{align}

for any $c \in (0,1)$.

What can we say about properties of $f(x)$?

An example, of a function that satisfies this is $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, $$f(x)=\prod_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ f( c^n x)}{f(c^{n+1} x)}$$ for every $x\ne0$ and $c$ in $(0,1)$, is equivalent to $$\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=1$$

Answer (score 1):

since the product telescopes the condition $f(0)=1$ might help. set 
$$
f_k(x)=\prod_{n=0}^k \frac{ f( c^n x)}{f(c^{n+1} x)} = \frac{f(x)}{f(c^{k+1}x)}
$$
as $c \in (0,1)$ we have $c^kx \to 0$ so if $f(0)=1$
$$
f_k(x) \to f(x)
$$

Comment: Can you explain this a little more. Are you suggestion that if impose an extra condition $f(0)=1$, then we can a get somewhere?

Comment: @Lisa He's saying the special case $x=0$ sets the telescoping sum to a product of ones, implying $f(0)=1$.

Comment: @J.G. Ok.  I get that now. Thanks.